# JQueryUI datepicker is not setting/posting the value of the textbox after a date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

The textbox starts with a value of 1/1/0001, which I am assuming is the default starting date for a new datetime.  The issue is that after a date is selected from the datepicker menu, the value on the HTML element is never changed and 1/1/0001 gets posted to the controller after the form is submitted.  The text within the textbox is changed, but when using the browser dev tools the value is still 1/1/0001.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row col-12 formdatepicker">
    <input asp-for="StartDate" type="text" class="form-control" id="startdatepicker" />
    <span style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px; padding-top: 5px;">to</span>
    <input asp-for="EndDate" type="text" class="form-control" id="enddatepicker" />
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function () {
            alert($('#startdatepicker').val());
        }
    });
    $("#enddatepicker").datepicker();

    var data = $('form').serialize();
    var dataType = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
    $(function () {
        $('#submit').on('click', function (evt) {
            console.log('Submitting form...');
            console.log(data);
            evt.preventDefault();
            //Ajax form post
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: data,
                contentType: dataType,
                url: '@Url.Action("Daily","Reports")',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        alert("Data Success");
                    } else {
                        console.log(data);
                        //Toggle the error modal and display error messages
                        $('#errorsModal').modal('toggle');
                        //Add <br> tags when there is a linebreak in the string.  This will add the line breaks into the HTML.
                        $('#errorsModal .modal-body p').html(data.message.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'));
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

The `.datepicker()` initializations are working correctly because the datepicker menu's are appearing when the textbox is clicked.  The onSelect alert never appears though when the value is changed.

Comment: You're calling `var data = $('form').serialize();` on doc ready - not just before you submit.  So you never get the value *after* it's changed.  Move `var data=` to just before `$.ajax({ data: data...`

Comment: "*The onSelect alert never appears*" - works fine - see https://jsfiddle.net/bnx3e4ud/ using your code + links to jquery/jquery-ui.

Comment: You can use the "Stack Snippet Starter Pack" detailed on the jquery-ui page (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-ui/info) to generate a [mcve] to demonstrate your issues if not covered by moving `var data = ` to the correct place.

Comment: @freedomn-m if you post your suggestion to move the variable as an answer, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks.